# Javascript generator if evaluation of yield expression

Tags: javascript

I was learning generators function in JavaScript and came across an example that the `next()` method is being used to pass value to the generator.

A `yield` expression is evaluated in an `if` statement (see line 3 in the following example)

I understand that passing a value that will be treated as truthy to replace the yield expression through `next(value)` will cause the `if` block to be executed.

But why isn't the if statement evaluation truthy anyway even if I do not pass any value through `next(value)`?
I got confused about the evaluation of if statement here in line 3, which of the following is the correct interpretation?

**A)** whenever the operation in line 3 "yield index++" operation succeed, it will be treated as truthy
(the operation nearly always succeed unless Javascript crashed, but actual behavior does not suggest this)

**B)** the return object of `next().done` gives value `false` it is treated as falsy
("done" value does gives "false" while the generator is not exhausted)

**C)** the return object of `next()` is `{"value": "some_value", "done": boolean}` is a truthy
(actual behavior does not suggest this)

**D)** other explanation

```js
//create a resettable generator that can be reset by passing value to generator through next(value)
function* resettableGen(index) {
  while (index < 3) {
    if(yield index++)
    {console.log("if block is executed, index will be reset.")
    index = 0};
  }
}

const foo = resettableGen(0);
//create a resettable generator object named Foo

console.log(foo.next());
//value pass to first next() call will be tossed away so do not pass value to next() here
//Object { value: 0, done: false }

console.log(foo.next(12));
//pass 12 to line 3 where yield expression will be replaced by the integer 12, since 12 is treated as truthy by if statement, if block is executed, index will be reset.
//Object { value: 0, done: false }

console.log(foo.next());
//Object { value: 1, done: false }

console.log(foo.next());
//Object { value: 2, done: false }

console.log(foo.next());
//Object { value: undefined, done: true }
```

Comment: When you don't pass anything into `.next()`, the `yield index++` evaluates to `undefined`, so it will be falsy

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield#syntax

`[rv] = yield [expression]`
>expression Optional
>Defines the value to return from the generator function via the iterator protocol.
> If omitted, undefined is returned instead.

What I do not understand is that `index++` is an expression that will be return to `.next()`, `[expression]` part is not omitted, so why is `undefined` returned?

Comment: The value that `yield [expression]` evaluates doesn't have anything to do with what `[expression]` evaluates to. `index++` evaluates to a number, which is returned via the generator in an IteratorResult object. What determines what `yield [expression]` evaluates to is based on what you pass into `.next()`. When you don't pass anything into it, you'll get `undefined`, when you do pass something into it, you'll get that value, such as `12`. So there are 2 different things being evaluated here `yield [expression]` and `[expression]`, the former is what is determined by the argument to `.next()`

Comment: Thank you, that clears things up. 
I was searching for the documentation on the evaluation of `yield [expression]` but to no avail.

All it mentioned was the omission of value will cause the `[expression]` part will return undefined, with nothing mention on the omission of value in `.next()` will cause `yield [expression]` part returning `undefined`...
(the only thing that I can confirm is `eval(yield [expression ])` does gives `undefined` when no value is passed to `.next()`)

Comment: No worries. It is documented in the [rv] part in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield#syntax#syntax) - _"rv > Retrieves the optional value passed to the generator's next() method to resume its execution."_. The value that gets evaluated by `yield [expression]` can be stored in a variable `rv` (that's what the docs are trying to say by writing _"[rv] = yield [expression]"_

Comment: I see. `rv` was used to store evaluation of `yield [expression]`.
indeed it can be confirmed using
```yieldEvaluation = yield index++
    console.log(yieldEvaluation);
```